# Submitting form using JQuery, AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form which submits it to the database using JQuery, AJAX and PHP. The problem is, whenever I click the `submit` button of the form, the JavaScript alert says that the record (data from the form) has successfully recorded (to the database). I would then check my database but the data is not recorded, leaving the database empty and no changes at all. My question is, there something wrong with the script? Or with the PHP code?

Here's the script `addnew.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
    var transMonth = $("#transMonth").val();
    var transDay = $("#transDay").val();
    var transYear = $("#transYear").val();
    var voucherNum = $("#voucherNum").val();
    var expType = $("#expType").val();
    var acctsPayable = $("#acctsPayable").val();
    var amount = $("#amount").val();

    var dataString = 'transMonth1='+ transMonth + 'transDay1='+ transDay + 'transYear1='+ transYear + 'voucherNum1='+ voucherNum + 'expType1='+ expType + 'acctsPayable1='+ acctsPayable + 'amount1='+ amount;
    if(voucherNum=='') {
        alert("Please fill a valid voucher number.");
    }
    else {
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "addnew.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result); 
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

Here's the PHP code `addnew.php`:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysql_select_db("mydb", $connection);

//fetch values

$transMonth2 = $_POST['transMonth1'];
$transDay2 = $_POST['transDay1'];
$transYear2 = $_POST['transYear1'];
$voucherNum2 = $_POST['voucherNum1'];
$expType2 = $_POST['expType1'];
$acctsPayable2 = $_POST['acctsPayable1'];
$amount2 = $_POST['amount1'];

//query

$query = mysql_query("insert into anotherSample(transMonth, transDay, transYear, voucherNum, expenseType, acctPayable, amount) values ('$transMonth2', '$transDay2', '$transYear2', '$voucherNum2', '$expType2', 'acctsPayable2', '$amount2')");
echo "Record added successfully";

mysql_close($connection);
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Use devtools in your browser to debug what is being sent and received from the ajax call.

Comment: If($query) echo "successful". Do this to check insert happening or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `dataString` in `addnew.js` should be `transMonth1='+ transMonth + '&transDay1='+ transDay + '&transYear1='...`,
otherwise the `$transDay2`,`$transYear2`..would be `null`, if your `transDay` or more set `NOT NULL` in mysql, there will occur a mysql error. :)

Comment: I did this and the code works fine now. I submit the form then checked the database, the data is recorded. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You should check returned result. You can do this by the following code:

```
$result = mysql_query("insert into anotherSample(transMonth, transDay, transMonth, transYear, voucherNum, expenseType, acctPayable, amount) values ('$transMonth2', '$transDay2', '$transYear2', '$voucherNum2', '$expType2', 'acctsPayable2', '$amount2')");

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); // only for development, in production you shouldn't print error to client!
}

echo "Record added successfully";

mysql_close($connection);
```

PS. Also, I advice you to read about SQL-injections, because your code is vulnerable.

Comment: I tried this and there was indeed something wrong with the query. I already edited it and posted the new code above.

Answer (score 1):

I see a problem in insert statement, insert into anotherSample(transMonth, transDay, transMonth, transYear,....) values ('$transMonth2', '$transDay2', '$transYear2, .....) 'transMonth' is repeated twice and eight columns with seven values.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I'm going to edit my code above and remove the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

In your addnew.js file you should use an ampersand (&) between each key/value pair like this:

```
var dataString = 'transMonth1='+ transMonth + '&transDay1='+ transDay + '&transYear1='+ transYear + '&voucherNum1='+ voucherNum + '&expType1='+ expType + '&acctsPayable1='+ acctsPayable + '&amount1='+ amount;
```

This way you will ensure that each variable will have a value when you are reading them in your addnew.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Check fetched values in `addnew.php`

and echo `mysql_error($connection)` to check if mysql error was occurred.